# How to get tag info for tags with special characters using SE API?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, api

Let's say we have the tag [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). How can I get its info with the Stack Exchange API? I tried doing `api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/c#/info`. However, it returns:

```
{"error_id":404,"error_message":"no method found with this name","error_name":"no_method"}
```

So do I encode the `#`? Or I can't access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Replace the `#` sign by `%23` and you'll get the tag:
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/c%23/info?site=stackoverflow

Comment: So its the javascript function `encodeURIComponent`? Seems like that turns it into the percent encoding

Comment: javascript? From this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent It looks like encodeURI is what you want, since it's the URI you're encoding.