# Do different Stack Exchange APIs treat encoded URIs differently?

Tags: discussion, tags, api

In our app, we're calling two Stack Exchange APIs:

- [get tags containing a given substring](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags)
- [get questions containing given tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)

We're encoding the tag name in both the calls, but in the former case, the API does not seem to decode the request. So, if I encode `C#` and send it as the `inname` value, it is not returning `c#` tag in the response. While the same case works for the get questions API call with encoding. So, should we actually encode the strings and send it or not?

Comment: Does [How to get tag info for tags with special characters using SE API?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261176) answer your question?

Comment: @Cai Not really, That post resolves the problem by suggesting encoding. My question is exactly the opposite. If I encode the tags, I'm not getting the expected tags as output. For eg., if I encode C# as C%23 I'm getting tags with 23 as a substring (like `emacs23`)

Comment: Works OK for me: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?inname=c%23&site=stackoverflow

Comment: Oh... seems it doesn't work on the console in the docs, is that where you're trying it?

Comment: I'm calling it from my code

Comment: Okay, it was my mistake, I was encoding it twice and that's why I couldn't get the correct tags. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Tags are lower-case only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216225/is-there-any-reason-why-tags-are-lower-cased), so your value of `C#` is not really correct in either place.
But [the `/questions` route is nice enough to ignore case](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=C%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), while the [`/tags` route is not](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&inname=C%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

**Using the correct case, [`/tags` works as expected](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&inname=c%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).**

So, yes, [you need to encode tag names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261176/how-to-get-tag-info-for-tags-with-special-characters-using-se-api), and you also need to lower-case them (generally).

Answer (score 0):

Percentage encoding should work for you. The following returns tags including the string "c#":

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?inname=c%23&site=stackoverflow

Encoding the character in the console on the docs page however doesn't work. It will encode your input so if you input already encoded characters it's just going to encode the "%" again (so "%23" will turn to "%2523")...

See this is double encoded:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&inname=c%2523&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Whereas this works:

> https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&inname=c%23&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

If you're having the same problem elsewhere then your input is being double encoded somewhere along the line, but it isn't a problem with the API.